# How can i get a value of read only mode text box using webdriver...I tried with gettext but it is not working

Tags: textbox, webdriver

Can any one help on this

How can i get a value of read only mode text box using webdriver...I tried with gettext but it is not working....

i gave a code as below

```
String Streetnumbercopare = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderInNestedMP_uclRiskInfo_txtStreetNumber")).getText();
if (StreetNumberTextValue.equals(Streetnumbercopare)) {
    System.out.println("Streetnumber matches --- Pass");
}else {
    System.out.println("Street number doesn't match --- Fail");
}
```

Comment: What about it 'doesn't work'?. Does it return anything? Throw an exception?

Answer (score 3):

I hade the same problem in python(using pytest)
If you also using python:
Try

*`element.get_attribute('value')`*
it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Try `driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderInNestedMP_uclRiskInfo_txtStreetNumber")).getAttribute("value")`

You might have HTML like here: [input tag example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit)